# Inserting widget into tab in Tab widget

Tags: c++, qt, tabwidget

I have problem with inserting widget into tab in Tab Widget. Because I'm trying make a simple web browser with tabs, I made a widget with some pushButtons and WebView, but when I want to add widget into a tab that I created dynamically (in code it is showed) it throw two errors:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: Error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Browsing::Browsing(class QWidget *)" (??0Browsing@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabBarDoubleClicked(int)" (?on_tabWidget_tabBarDoubleClicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXH@Z***)

and

> debug\Pluto.exe:-1: Error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

#### browsing.cpp:

```
    #include "browsing.h"
    #include "ui_browsing.h"
    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

    Browsing::Browsing(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Browsing)
    {
        ui->webView->load(QString("http://google.com"));
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    Browsing::~Browsing()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void Browsing::on_backButton_clicked()
    {
        ui->webView->back();
    }

    void Browsing::on_forwardButton_clicked()
    {
        ui->webView->forward();
    }

    void Browsing::on_reloadButton_clicked()
    {
        ui->webView->reload();
    }


    void Browsing::on_searchLine_returnPressed()
    {
        ui->webView->load(QString("http://"+ui->searchLine->text()));
    }
```

#### mainwindow.cpp:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include "browsing.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)
    {
        ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
    }

    void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabBarDoubleClicked(int index)
    {
        //ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(),new Browsing(),QIcon(QString("")),"New tab"); -- also not working
        ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(),new Browsing(new QWidget(ui->tabWidget)),"New Tab");
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(index + 1);
    }

    void MainWindow::on_addButton_clicked()
    {
        //ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(),new Browsing(),QIcon(QString("")),"New tab");
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);

    }
```

#### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index);

    void on_tabWidget_tabBarDoubleClicked(int index);

    void on_addButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

#### Browsing.h:

```
    #ifndef BROWSING_H
#define BROWSING_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Browsing;
}

class Browsing : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Browsing(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Browsing();

private slots:
    void on_backButton_clicked();

    void on_forwardButton_clicked();

    void on_reloadButton_clicked();

    void on_searchLine_returnPressed();

private:
    Ui::Browsing *ui;
};

#endif // BROWSING_H
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything is wrong with your .cpp files. Perhaps it is a missing ";" within browsing.h at the end of a class-declaration?

Comment: nope all is right :-) want you see my header file?

Comment: What do you try to achieve with this line? `new Browsing(new QWidget(ui->tabWidget)` ? `Browsing` constructor does not use parent at all, so why do you try to give for new Browsing object parent new QWidget that will have tabWidget as parent?

Comment: I recommend put `ui->setupUi(this);`  in Browsing ctor to be called first.

Comment: Radek: if i understand: insert ui->setupUi(this); before ui->webView->load(QString("http://google.com"));

Comment: Please add the headers

Comment: killdaclick fixed :-)